# While loop encountered the symbol > error

Tags: sql, oracle, while-loop

```
DECLARE
totalspendamt NUMBER(6,2) := 100;
itemprice NUMBER(6,2) := 129.99;
qty NUMBER(6,2) :=1;
WHILE 
totalspendamt >= itemprice LOOP 
totalspendamt := totalspendamt - itemprice; 
qty := qty + 1; 
END LOOP;
```

The above code calculates the total quantity of a specified item that can be purchased with a given amount of money. I keep getting an error on ">" Encountered the symbol ">" when expecting one of the following...

Comment: Still the same error, even if i remove > and just leave = it will give me the same error for =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `BEGIN/END` block

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/3979/0)**

```
DECLARE
totalspendamt NUMBER(6,2) := 100.0;
itemprice NUMBER(6,2) := 129.99;
qty NUMBER(6,2) :=1;
BEGIN
WHILE totalspendamt >= itemprice LOOP 
totalspendamt := totalspendamt - itemprice; 
qty := qty + 1; 
END LOOP; 
END;
```